# Problems while trying to import css file to vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js

So I'm building my first vue app but I cant manage to find a way to import external CSS files under `/assets/css`. Is there a way to import external css files with vue? Do I need an extra package for this?

**What I tried:**

In main.js I tried adding `import '@/assets/css/menu.css';` but it returns the following error when building the app:

```
 error  in ./src/assets/css/menu.css

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/menu-back.svg' in 'C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\src\assets\css'
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:925:10
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:213:14
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\amng8\Desktop\Ruby\app\client\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43

 @ ./src/pages/index/main.js 7:0-31
 @ multi ./src/pages/index/main.js
```

Also tried to include

```
<link href="assets/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/baseunit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in the index.html under `/public` but apparently it can only get files from `/public` and I don't know if I should leave the files in the `/public` directory.

**File directory print:**

[image]

PS: I'm using a multi-page setup in this vue app.

I think that's all I tested.
I'm new to vue.js so if you need any extra info let me know.

Comment: where is the menu-back.svg?

Comment: Didnt add it yet. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
import './assets/css/menu.css'
```

Oh! I see you have your main.js in src/pages/index/main.js For this reason is not working.. Your main.js must be in src/main.js

If you want to keep your main.js in that path (src/pages/index/main.js), you need to change to

```
import '../../assets/css/menu.css'
```

Comment: I suppose I should add that in the `script` tag but gives me this error: `This relative module was not found:

* ./assets/css/menu.css in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&`

Comment: I tested in my vue app before answer and is working. I add in main.js

Comment: Oh! I see you have your main.js in src/pages/index/main.js For this reason is not working.. Your main.js must be in src/main.js 

I have edited the answer

Comment: Worked! How about js I tried doing the same thing but it gives a lot of errors. Do you know a way to import js files too?